# Changes to CSS Mobile Query No Longer Responding

Tags: css, mobile, media-queries

A few years ago I made a website where I used CSS media queries to format for mobile. Today, in working on updating the site, it seems as if any changes I'm making to the mobile queries aren't responding.

HTML is set up like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

CSS Media Queries are set up like this (for portrait and landscape orientations):

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

The code I previously wrote still works, but any new changes don't show up. Anyone know why this is happening?

Also, full website is here: https://estherloui.se/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `min-width` instead of `min-device-width` same for height

Comment: No difference. Was there a change in formatting for media queries in CSS since 2017?